# What is it that makes an electron maintain a distance from the positively charged nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

What is it that makes an electron maintain a distance from the positively charged nucleus? Why aren't electrons merely pulled into and absorbed by the nucleus ?

Comment: Another good duplciate: [Why do electrons occupy the space around nuclei, and not collide with them?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9415/) and related [Why doesn't orbital electron fall into the nucleus of Rb85, but falls into the nucleus of Rb83?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4481/520).

Comment: I am going to write an answer on http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9415/, as a layman simply cannot connect seemingly with some of these responses. I do wish I knew LaTex a little better, so bear with me.